# Where's __proto__? - JavaScript Classes

Tags: javascript, class

i'm new to JavaScript and now just learning about classes.
Where i learned from (JavaScript.info), it is said that class `extends` sets the prototype value of the parent class as `__proto__` of the child class. Meaning i can just do something like:

```js
(ChildClass.__proto__ === ParentClass) // true
```

But something else happens.
Have a look at this block of code i wrote:

```js
class thing {
    constructor() {
        console.log("hello")
    }

    doAThing() {
        console.log("Doing a very cpu heavy thing.")
    }
}

class extraThing extends thing {
    doAnotherThing() {
        console.log("doing another thing")
    }
}

let thing1 = new thing();
let thing2 = new extraThing();

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(thing1.__proto__));
// [ 'constructor', 'doAThing' ] - links to itself because theres no __proto__ set...

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(thing2.__proto__));
// [ 'constructor', 'doAnotherThing' ] - links to itself although it extends "thing".?
```

I can't understand what's happening... Where does the child class take the parent class's methods from if its not in `__proto__`.

By the way, as far as i understood, when you call a class with `new`, it just runs the constructor as a normal constructor function, making classes just a syntactic suger (???).
And as far as i know, constructor functions (normal functions that are ran with `new`) just return an object. So i assume that objects or instances that are returned by a class are just normal objects...

Although, i am aware that there are differences. Constructor functions that are ran under a class have a hidden property named `[[IsClassConstructor]]`, but i don't understand how that would change the returned object, because as far as i know, it just changes the behavior of `new` (like not letting you call a class without `new`).

Comment: [Probably forget about `__proto__`; there are better ways of doing things now.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto)

Comment: @Pointy i am aware of Object.getPrototypeOf() and Object.setPrototypeOf(), i just used `__proto__` for this question.

Comment: "*`ChildClass.__proto__ === ParentClass`, but something else happens*" - well that's not what your code is looking at. In your example, it would be `extraThing.__proto__ === thing`, which is indeed true. But you're looking at the prototype objects! The prototype of `thing1` is `thing.prototype`, and the prototype of `thing2` is `extraThing.prototype`, and the prototype of `extraThing.prototype` is `thing.prototype` - which is actually the more relevant thing that `extends` does, since this is what allows you to access `thing2.doAThing()`.

Comment: I tried also accessing `thing1.prototype`, but it returned undefined.

Comment: `.prototype` is a property of the class (constructor function), not of the instance.